Computing Daily MTM from a Trade log of a Positional Strategy
I've generated the trade log shown below based on a positional strategy. There may be multiple or no trades on any given day.

The log includes entry/exit times and prices, and I also have access to daily 1-minute OHLC data for the instrument I'm trading.
My goal is to write a Python script to compute the daily Mark-to-Market (MTM) values and feed them into the QuantStats package to generate a performance tearsheet for the strategy.
To the best of my knowledge, daily MTM is required for generating the tearsheet using QuantStats. However, if there’s a more efficient way to use this trade log to create the tearsheet, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you in advance for your help!

This question isn't about Quantitative Finance, its about summing up a column "net_pnl"  in a DataFrame or in SQL grouped by date and then inputting that data to an external software. This question is best asked elsewhere.

@Attack68 I was little confused about posting here or stackoverflow as it was little programming oriented, but thought this community's people probably has better idea about the tearsheet or quantstats. I will post this question else where. Should I close this?
